# Can I delete my account?

Tags: support

I don't want to have this site available anymore. It's not that I find people voting down my questions insulting, but it gets on my last nerve.

People should not vote down questions that are a suitable fit to this site. Everything I post is better referenced etc. that 90% of everything else.

Comment: Note: I'm upvoting that "how do I delete my account" is a good question, not as an indication that you deleting your account is a good idea.

Comment: StackExchange is so-so for programming but not for much more. I'm leaving too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to delete your stack exchange account.

See [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

for the steps you would need to take.

Comment: The "delete option" isn't there what can I do?

Comment: @PbxMan you should choose the "contact stackexchange" and ask for deletion, then you get a mail for further instructuions. i would, but then i wouldn't be able to comment or vote etc., if i popped back