# If Einstein were in SE

Tags: discussion

A question popped up in me when I saw [this](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/can-i-delete-my-account).

There are several subjects that deal with abstract ideas eg. Philosophy.  Philosophy includes sections that need not only intelligence but also great wisdom (eg. Truth, Pure consciousness).  But people having both these qualities are rare.

Sometimes words of great wisdom seem like a foolishness.  Silly people like me can't understand ideas dealing here.  But voting, closing and deleting is going on without any interruption even without keeping it for one or two years.

**How wisdom and voting go hand in hand?**

If Einstein signs in here with a New Relativity Theory, isn't there a chance of deleting his views because of downvotes?

How wise-newbies can view his explanation if it is deleted?

What will happen to my question if I can't respond for many months even if it contains many bits of good ideas?

Comment: c.f.http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30217/are-methodological-assumptions-of-stackexchange-fundamentally-flawed/30236

Comment: Philosophy SE is not for original philosophy or debate.  It is to answer questions ABOUT philosophy, not philosophy questions *per se*.  If a great philosopher posted original work here about subject Y, it would be off-topic, because it's making original claims about Y that aren't verified anywhere else.  On the other hand, a question about "what has Great Philosopher X written about Y" would be on topic, because it has a objective, supportable answer. (That's not to say we all don't sneak in original opinions from time to time).

Comment: Why post it here rather than on Physics SE? For that matter, why post it on SE at all instead of submitting a publication for peer review? If opposed to that he could go Perelman and post detailed accounts on arxiv, which get attention of experts, or even start a blog. It's not like there is a shortage of ways to vent original ideas these days, the trick is to have ones worth venting. And Einstein got quite a bit of real life "downvotes" in his time, such is real life.

Comment: Normally Philosophers having great wisdom (i.e., those who realized the Truth won't sign in SE). They don't go for any argument without any cause. They know what is argument. Actually I meant the sections of highly complicated ideas (Truth, Pure Consciousness etc.).  Those who didn't realize these.... Are they eligible for giving 'upvote' or 'downvote'. My question was on closing, deleting following the same rule. I got many ideas about SE's rules from your comments. Thanks.
@user4894: That means roasting is being done by Philosophers. Then will SE get more new-users?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is that potential. But with all new theories, they must overcome that potential whether it is on SE or elsewhere. The trials of both Galileo and Socrates are perfect examples of this need to push against current wisdom, despite the negativity of the masses or even the "elite" of both the field of study and of society in general. So if one answer is down voted, I'd say rework your explanation and resubmit. Or perhaps fortify your answer with evidence that supports it. That is the whole purpose of SE. One answer being lost does not amount to all is lost.

Answer (score -2):

SE can leave the following message at the end of such questions (with a Hyperlink).

*"If you are interested in this question you may view a few Deleted answers that are put aside due to some reasons.  Don't forget to leave your comments in the space provided.  We will be giving appropriate consideration to them."*

The comments should be verified every year and make them visible to all users if they have any valuable ideas.

In this list SE may avoid questions or answers that have any insulting remarks that degrade SE.

Answer (score -2):

Genius and madness are indistinguishable to the mediocre, as both are equally alien and incomprehensible to them.

For that reason, ...

> Great spirits have always encountered violent opposition from mediocre
>   minds.
>
> — Albert Einstein

However, also know that...

> To attempt to silence a man is to pay him homage, for it is an
>   acknowledgement that his arguments are both impossible to answer and
>   impossible to ignore.
>
> — John "Birdman" Bryant

And...

> All truth passes through three stages. First, it is ridiculed. Second,
>   it is violently opposed. Third, it is accepted as being self-evident.
>
> — Arthur Schopenhauer

---

So, to answer your question regarding Einstein : yes, the chance would be great that many (if not most) of his posts would be downvoted and/or deleted.

The chance is also great that he wouldn't take it personal, as great minds are used to great opposition from the mediocre masses wherever they go.